# Quais ferramentas/frameworks estão disponíveis para criar uma API restful em PHP?

Tags: php, api, restful

Existe alguma ferramenta desse tipo que facilite o desenvolvimento de uma API RESTful?
Já ouvi falar do Slim Framework, mas queria conhecer mais ferramentas.

-----editada
Pra ser mais específico, quero fazer uma API RESTful pra pegar dados de um BD MySQL e usar isso com varias interfaces diferentes, de forma corporativa, apenas dentro da minha empresa.
 Então pra resumir, preciso de flexibilidade e segurança.

Comment: Você poderia especificar melhor o que você está tentando fazer? Você diz "ferramentas desse tipo", mas a qual tipo você se refere afinal?

Comment: Cesar, sugiro alterar sua pergunta para algo como "Quais ferramentas ..." perguntas do tipo "Qual o melhor..." possivelmente será fechada por ser baseada em opiniões.

Answer (score 1):

O Slim realmente facilita, porém sugiro você dar uma analisada no Silex, que é um microframework construído com base nos componentes do Symfony2, sendo tão fácil como o Slim, porém com mais recursos.

Comment: Tambem vale lembrar o Lumen, mini framework basedo no Laravel.

Comment: Até então não conhecia, mas parece ser bem interessante. Valeu por compartilhar.